# How to deselect a text box in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

For any help thanks in advance and
Here my code is:

```
<input type="text" id="hoEndDate" name="endDate" class="endDatePicker" required/>
```

js code is:

```
$('#hoEndDate').setAttribute("disabled", true);
```

Comment: `$("#duration").prop("disabled",true)`

Comment: Do you mean deselect (remove focus) or do you mean disable (make it read only)

Comment: Just to be sure, are you talking about _deselecting_ the text in a textbox, or making a textbox _disabled_?

Comment: There is no setAttribute in jQuery. I am sure your developer console has an error message that states that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set disabled attribute like this:

```
$("#duration").attr("disabled","disabled")
```

OR

```
$("#duration").prop("disabled",true)
```

Comment: `disabled` is a property, use `.prop` instead.

Comment: i want to deselect the text in a textbox.

Answer (score 2):

by deselect if you mean to remove focus,

```
$("#duration").blur()
```

or to disable

```
$("#duration").attr("disabled","disabled")
```

Comment: for select box i wrote like this           $('select#endTimeMins option').removeAttr("selected");
but for text box how to remove the selected value?

Comment: please give me solution.

Comment: @sireeshaj there is not any way to deselect value in text box you have to blank the text field by using these $("#duration").val("");

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by

```
$("#duration").attr("disabled","disabled")
```